# Trying to get an Impersonation Level of Delegate in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, delegates, impersonation

I am trying to setup a Web API that will, when needed, call a backend Server with the calling Users creds.

So, User (User1) calls API, API runs under IIS Application Pool with its own Service Account (WebApp) which I am trying to get to impersonate User1 to access backend server.

I can Impersonate but only to an ImpersonationLevel of Impersonate which only gives me access to local resources. To Impersonate to a remote server I need an ImpersonationLevel of Delegate.

Compiling using VS2017, C# Web Project, ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) with an Empty project template with "Web API" checked. No option to set Authentication with these options.

Code to Impersonate is

```
WindowsImpersonationContext myImpersonation = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity)Impersonate();
```

Using this code to show Impersonation Level (have also verified with local resources and WireShark).

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel
```

I think I have set Kerberos delegation OK including SPNs.

Can anyone tell me if the code above should give me an ImpersonationLevel of Delegate (Is the code OK)? If not what should I be doing in code? Are the Project settings OK?

Comment: How did you configure delegation in AD? Either that is misconfigured, or you're missing the SeImpersonatePrivilege for the app pool running as WebApp.

Comment: @Steve The App Pool Account has got the SeImpersonatePrivilege by dint of it being a member of IIS_IUSR and I think I read somewhere that Windows gives that right to all App Pool Service Accounts anyway. I have checked it by using whoami /priv while running a PS shell as that user *and* as an Administrator. If I run whoami /priv in a non-admin then that priv is not showing which is consistent with UAC stripping out admin provs from a users token. Should I somehow be impersonating the full admin token? How would I do that?

Comment: That looks about right then. I guess one important thing worth checking... have you actually tried requesting a delegated ticket for the user? This might just be an artifact of how Impersonate() is called before being used to request a ticket.

Comment: @Steve feels to me like I'm missing something. I'm doing this `((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity)Impersonate();` and then checking the ImpersonationLevel by using this `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel`. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`. This shows the expected Name change.I'm curious about what you mean by "requesting a delegated ticket for the user".  I'm just calling Impersonate and then attempting to access the remote resource.

Comment: Right. I'm asking if the remote resource is in fact accessible or are you just deciding based on the ImpersonationLevel value? The impersonated identity must come from a Kerberos ticket originally, otherwise you're going to do what's called protocol transition where you suggest to AD that you should authenticate the user instead of AD. Protocol transition is blocked by default because it's dangerous.

Comment: Yes, the remote server is accessible when I don't try to use Impersonation, that is from the App Pool Account. Also the Impersonation I get is effective locally in that the code can access or not a local resource (file) which is locked down to the Identity calling the API dependent on whether or not Impersonation is invoked. The exact call is to a Windows CA which is loosely permissioned so that the App Pool Identity can access it. This is in Dev, in Prod will want this to be only the calling Users ID. Code called is to `CCertRequest()` which is via an Interop. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you authenticating the user in the first place? Are you using Kerberos or doing something else? If something else, this by design will not work unless you enable protocol transition.

Comment: @Steve The setup is a bit more complicated than I said. It is using an ADFS Server with a non-claims aware Relying Party and a WAP server to use Kerberos to authenticate. I can see the WAP Server getting Kerberos tokens. This setup is borrowed from how to use ADFS/WAP to authenticate to MIM which was a Technet (I think) blog post which has recently disappeared. The WAP Server is set to Delegate to the Web Server with Protocol Transition. Could the WAP Server actually be doing NTLM to the Web Server?

Comment: So client (ADFS) > WAP (prot trans) > App (kerb deleg) > App2? And you want App2 to receive a delegated ticket? WAP > App will not do NTLM if protocol transition is in play (it can't).

Comment: Here is more detail. The WAP Server is set to Delegation->Trust this Computer... ->Use any... .On authenticating with `User`, and getting a response from the Web Server we have two User Logons on the WAP Server. The first is to `localhost` done with `explicit credentials` the second uses Kerberos. We have two Kerberos tokens under the Logon ID of the second Logon, one of which is for http/<Web API URL>. On looking at the Web Server that has a single Logon from `User` and a single Kerberos token under that Logon ID for the Web API URL. All tokens are forwardable. I still suspect the code.

Comment: So, for me, given that the Web Server has a forwardable Kerberos Token, how do I get the Web API code to use that to get a 'second hop' Kerberos token to the backend server?

Comment: The Kerberos ticket is ingested through `AcceptSecurityContext` which dumps out an NT Token. Windows decides the impersonation level of the token based on the permissions of the server app. With the NT token as the security context, any call to `InitializeSecurityContext` should automatically impersonate and get a new kerb ticket.